# Problem in changing text in pyqt5 in text browser

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried so many things so that I can show my users that when the program is Listening to their voice input. I tried to show it on a text browser in pyqt5 but I have not got any result. Whenever I try to show it along with the Microphone running in the background. Then it was crashing. Stack Overflow I used Threading. Now it is running perfectly. But I am not able to show text on the text browser. I can show text but I want to change it based on condition. So can anyone tell me which function/format/method or code I should use.

This question already exists:
Problem in changing text in pyqt5 in text browser
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed yesterday.

(Private feedback for you)

Keep This code in a separate file:- This code is the example of this question:- Problem in changing text in pyqt5 in text browser So someone asked me to give example code so I am writing this new post to give them this example:-

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr

class Example(object):
    def setupUi(self, Example):
        Example.setObjectName("Example")
        Example.resize(454, 800)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Example)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.bg_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.bg_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-6, 0, 461, 801))
        self.bg_1.setText("")
        self.bg_1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("G.U.I Material/B.G/Black_Template.jpg"))
        self.bg_1.setScaledContents(True)
        self.bg_1.setObjectName("Background_1")

        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 380, 301, 161))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;\n""border-radius:none;")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")

        
        self.Start_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Start_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 690, 191, 91))
        self.Start_Button.setCheckable(True)
        self.Start_Button.setText("Stop")
        self.Start_Button.setStyleSheet("font: 75 51pt \"Calibri\";\n""background-color: rgb(85, 170, 0);")
        self.Start_Button.setObjectName("Start_Button")
        
        Example.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(Example)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Example)

    def retranslateUi(self, Example):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Example.setWindowTitle(_translate("Example", "Example"))
        self.Start_Button.setText(_translate("Example", "Start"))
```

Now keep this code in a separate file:-

```
from YOURFILENAME import Example
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr

class MainThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainThread, self).__init__()
    
    def run(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()

        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            self.textBrowser.setText("Listening...")
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            r.energy_threshold = 4000
            audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            self.textBrowser.setText("Recognizing...")
            query = r.recognize_google(audio,language="en-in")
            self.textBrowser.setText(f"User : {query}")

        except:
            return ""

        query = str(query)
        return query.lower()

StartExecution = MainThread()

class GUI_Start(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.gui = Example()
        self.gui.setupUi(self)

        self.gui.Start_Button.clicked.connect(self.Start_Task)
    
    def Start_Task(self):
        if self.gui.Start_Button.isChecked():
            self.gui.Start_Button.setText("Stop")
            self.gui.label = QtGui.QMovie("C:\\Users\\hp\\PycharmProjects\\My Personal Assistant Project\\G.U.I Material\\VoiceReg\\Ntuks.gif")
            self.gui.Gif_1.setMovie(self.gui.label)
            self.gui.label.start()
            self.MainFunctions()
                
        else:
            self.gui.Start_Button.setText("Start")
            self.gui.label.stop()
            StartExecution.terminate()

    def MainFunctions(self):
        while self.gui.Start_Button.isChecked():
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            StartExecution.start()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = GUI_Start()
gui.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

This is producing the issue.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks for replying here is the minimal reproducible example:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065462/example-code-for-a-question-already-posted-related-to-pyqt5-and-python

Comment: @PrachiKakkad use the [edit] link to provide your code, don't create a new question! Please follow the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Okay, I did the thing suggested by you. So now please give me its solution if you know it.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)